# How to create url mapping for Portlet in Websphere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal

I have a web module ( a portlet) deployed on my local installation of IBM portal server v6.0.

After deploying the portlet I have added it to the portlet menu which is how I am accessign it. When I navigate to the Portlet in the Portal I get a non-reable url.

I am aware that you can create a url mapping to map the web module to a human radable url and I can see the URL mapping in the Portal Menu but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can someone please help me with some instructions on how to do it.

thanks

Comment: What is portlet menu? if it just put portlet on portal page and want access it by readable URL, you can create Url mapping in portal administration. WPS 6 too old and it's pages doesn't have friendly url fields.

Comment: This. Yes I figured out how to create the url mapping to the Portlet using the administration menu.